# Как в готовом коде убрать первую цифру ноль у некоторых чисел?

Tags: php

Допустим, есть массив с числами:

```
$arr = [2, 6, 08, 1];
```

Из-за того, что у некоторых чисел первой цифрой идет 0, выходит ошибка, так как php воспринимает их в качестве восьмиричных чисел.
Как избавить такие числа от первого нуля? Чтобы 08 превратилось в 8.
При этом сделать это надо в момент объявления массива, так как любые циклы, написанные после массива, уже не обрабатываются, то есть ошибка выходит уже на этапе объявления массива.

Comment: foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {$arr1[]=(int)$value;}

Comment: Но дело в том, что ошибку выдает еще перед тем, как срабатывает цикл. На то, что в массиве уже есть такие числа, он выдает ошибку: Parse error: Invalid numeric literal

Comment: в яндексе поищи там много всего.

Comment: Так исправить в исходнике скрипта ))

Comment: Число исправить? Просто такова задача. Подобных чисел, начинающихся с 0, в массиве может быть множество. Я просто привел упрощенный пример.

Comment: Что такое "такова задача"? Кто её поставил? Кому? Зачем?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу проблему. Внесите [правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1309611/edit) в вопрос, чтобы сообщество могло вам дать однозначный ответ. Какой размер массива?

Comment: Размер массива не имеет значения. Проблема в том, что когда в массиве число начинается с 0, php распознает его как восьмиричное, а восьмиричном числе не может быть цифр 8 и 9. И на число 08, например, он выдаст ошибку. Поэтому я хочу понять, возможно ли уже на этапе объявления массива убрать у его элементов нули, если они стоят в начале чисел.

Comment: Возможно. Надо просто **не писать нули** на этапе объявления массива.

Comment: "возможно ли уже на этапе объявления массива убрать у его элементов нули, если они стоят в начале чисел"... Конечно возможно. Поставте курсор после нуля, который вы хотите убрать, и нажмите клавишу "Backspace" на клавиатуре.

Answer (score 3):

Числовой литерал, начинающийся нулём, в PHP есть число в восьмеричной системе счисления. Если такое число содержит символ цифры 8 или 9 (или нецифровой символ), то для восьмеричной системы это некорректный литерал, что и вызывает указанную ошибку. Данная ошибка является синтаксической и не может быть исправлена программно, ибо выявляется ещё до начала выполнения кода.

Исправляйте текст скрипта. Другого варианта - нет.